# About growth rate of the iterated exponential on the complex plane.

Tags: complex-numbers, dynamical-systems, tetration, complex-dynamics

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $f(n,x) = exp(f(n-1,x))$ and $f(0,x)=x$.
Let $Q(f(n,x)) =1$ if $Re(f(n,x))<2$. Let $S(n,x) = \Sigma_{1}^{n}  Q(f(n,x))$.

How to estimate $S(n,2+i)$ efficiently ?

Comment: I don't think there is a much better method than calculating explicitly here. With ergodic theoretic tools you can get results like "for most initial conditions x (in a certain sense) S(n,x)/n will converge to a certain constant, but it won't work with a particular initial condition.

Comment: If I recall the dynamical behaviour is non trivial, with a fat set of initial conditions leading to orbits dense in the plane, so it's not an easy question a priori. Unless I'm missing something and we can say something about the orbit of $2+i$ in particular.

Comment: How to compute your constant ?

Comment: well that is only part of the reasoning, but if you find an ergodic measure $\mu$ (and there are some) then theorems from ergodic theory will tell you that S(n,x)/n will converge to $\mu(H)$ where $H$ is the set of complex numbers with real part <2, for every $x$ outside a set of measure 0 (for $\mu$).

Comment: So the question amounts to finding an "interesting" ergodic measure, ideally one wich is at density with respect to the Lebesgues measure (I don't think there are though).